# Get records with key=id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-1.9.3

How to get records from the database with key=id

```
items = Item.all
```

Instead of:

```
items = {{"id"=>1, "title"=>"A"},
{"id"=>5, "title"=>"B"}}
```

How to get?

```
items = {"1"=>{"id"=>1, "title"=>"A"},
"5"=>{"id"=>5, "title"=>"B"}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Ruby >= 2.0 or Ruby < 2.0 with [backports](https://github.com/marcandre/backports):

```
Item.all.map { |r| [r.id, r.attributes] }.to_h
```

For Ruby < 2.0 without backports:

```
Hash[Item.all.map { |r| [r.id, r.attributes] }]
```

Comment: Thanks, it almost works! I got `[[30, #<Item id: 30, category_id: 21, user_id: 1, name: "Paul Fredrick Men's Luxury Cotton Straight Collar B...", url: "paul-fredrick-mens-luxury-cotton-straight-collar-b", text: "<div>luxury 140's 2-ply cotton</div><div>Luxury 140...", status: true, created_at: "2014-02-04 10:08:47", updated_at: "2014-02-16 16:46:03", position: 2, price: #<BigDecimal:7f9938365eb0,'0.895E2',18(18)>, old_price: nil, homepage: true, weight: nil, limit: nil>]]` with double brackets. and to_h gives undefined function

Comment: Which Ruby vrsion are you using?

Comment: As value do you need the record or the record attributes?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52759/discussion-between-gediminas-and-mdesantis)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following :

```
result = {}
Item.all.collect{|item| result[item.id] = item.as_json}
```